# When should I make a repository for my project?

Tags: c++, version-control, netbeans, mercurial, project

I've been looking into using Mercurial for version management and wanted to try it out. I'm planning on doing a project on my own to help me learn C++ coming from Java and thought it would be a good idea to try version management with it. It would probably be a game or some sort of simple application, not sure with a GUI or not.

The problem is I don't know much about version management. When in a project is a good time to make the repository? Should I just do it right away? How often should I make commits?

I'll be using Netbeans for my development since it seems to be pretty good, also has Mercurial controls built in, but what should I set in the .hgignore for my project? I assume the repository would be the whole folder Netbeans creates but what should I make it ignore?

*Bonus questions*: I'll be using Bitbucket for hosting/backup, should I make the project public? Why/why not? Also would that make it open source? Should I bother with attaching a license? Because I have no idea how the licenses work and such. Then again, I sincerely doubt I'll be making anything anyone will want to copy too badly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### On repos:

You should use a VCS repository as soon as possible. Not only does it allow for off-site backups, but it allows you to track changes. To find out when a bug was introduced.

Having a VCS, particularly a distributed VCS like Mercurial, will change the way you code. You won't have to be careful not to break things, because you always have the old version that you can revert to. If, after a few weeks or months, you decide that a particular course of development was a bad idea, you can rewind all the way back to some prior point.

You should generally commit either every day, or every time you finish a task. Like, you might have a 4-hour task of "write this class and get it working". You commit after that. When you're done for the day, you commit. I wouldn't suggest committing in a non-compiling state, though, so you should try to stop for the day only when everything still builds.

As for ignoring, you should ignore things you don't intend to commit. Things that you wouldn't want in the repo. Generated files, temporary files, the stuff that you wouldn't need.

What should be in the repo is 100% of the information necessary to build the project from scratch (minus external dependencies).

### On licenses:

I would say that it is very rude to put up a public repository without some kind of license attached. Without a license, that means that anyone even pulling from the repo (which is what you're inviting by making it public) is a violation of your copyright without direct, explicit permission from you.

So either look at how copyright works and pick a license to release your stuff under, or keep your repos private.

Comment: +1 for "100% of the information necessary to build the project from scratch". I can't tell you how aggravating it is checking out a project that can't be built unless you scatter your chicken bones just right.

Comment: Ditto.  I always tell people to commit as often as possible, though.  You can always branch and/or rebase.  I guess it depends on the context - in a big dev house a bunch of commits could get cumbersome, but for someone learning I think having lots of incremental steps to look back through is a good thing.

Comment: Nicol Bolas and @Chris. Thanks for the advice, chose Nicol's because it was more detailed. For the ignore file I was looking for examples of .hgignore code people had made for Netbeans C++ projects and what they do. For licenses I guess I'll have to make a new question thread since it deviates from the main topic too much.

Answer (score 4):

The instant you conceive of it, usually. There is no penalty for putting everything you have into a VCS right away, and who knows, you may want that super-duper prototype version later on down the road. Unless you're going to be checking in large media files (don't), my answer is: right now.

As for how often to commit, that's a personal preference. I use git, and as far as I'm concerned there is no problem with checking in every time you make some unit of significant change. The more snapshots along the way you have, the easier it becomes to track down bugs later on.

Your .hgignore is up to you. You need to decide what to version and what not to. As a rule of thumb, any files generated during compilation probably shouldn't be checked in.

Also, if you release it to the public, please attach a license. It doesn't matter what it is, but it makes all the bosses and lawyers in the world happy when they know what they can and can't do with your code. Finally, please don't release something to the public unless you think someone else will benefit from it. The internet already suffers from information overload.

Comment: +1 for good advice, though I disagree with "The internet already suffers from information overload."  In the age of Facebook and Twitter...?

Comment: *especially* in the age of Facebook and Twitter.

Comment: That's like complaining about someone having a quiet conversation on the other side of a crowded stadium... :P

Comment: 2 billion people whispering in a stadium gets pretty loud. You're mistaking machine capacity with human capacity. I'm saying this: don't pollute the internet with garbage. And yes, twitter and facebook are 99.9% garbage, which means it's harder to find what's actually important. Github / bitbucket are filled with half-baked projects that look perfect in a google search.

Answer (score 0):

Commit early, and commit often.

With distributed VCS like hg or git there's really no reason not to start a repo before you even write any code.  If you decide to scrap your project, you can always delete your repo before you post it to whatever hosting site you're using.  The more often you commit, the easier it will be to hone in on where you messed up later on (you will).

Stuff to put in your ignore file would be build files and anything that your IDE generates periodically, like user preferences and tag caches.  You don't want to foist your preferences on someone else and you don't want to have to create a commit every time you change the position of a window in the IDE.  What's in the repo should be the minimum that someone would need to be able to work on your project.

If you're just doing a small project to learn, then I wouldn't worry about licenses or having a private repo.  You can always add a license later.  Alternatively, just pick a permissive license and go with it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience with `git`, I would recommend the following:

1. Create repository along with project.
2. Commit as often as you can with detailed comments
3. When you want to test a new idea - create a branch. If the idea is successful, merge your code to the master branch. If the idea is not successful, you can just discard the branch. Probably this is the most important idea.
4. Put the names of object files, executables and editor backup files in the ignore list.